# Distinction between two types of self

Tags: self, self-cognition

Teleporting persons and multiple "you's" are discussed in serious thought experiments in physics and philosophy.

I feel like most of the time these scenarios come up, I would not make the same assumptions I feel the experimenters do however. The problem is, most of the time they never explain their assumptions that allow them to make the claims they do.

When I think of the self, I can't picture how it can be teleported along with the rest of the body. This is due to how I picture the duplicator version of the thought experiment. In the duplicator, nothing happens to your original body. Instead of being decomposed and beamed then recomposed, your original body remains unaffected, and a duplicate is beamed instead. There are now two materially identical versions of you, each with their own conscious experiences. When the consciousness of the version of me on Mars feels pain, my consciousness on Earth does not. And vice versa.

Thus I would never take a transporter because I believe your self must die every time. If it did not die, I can't explain the duplicator version.

But then I hear other serious philosophers and physicists think no, *you* would wake up on Mars. Or in quantum immortality, *you* will live forever, instead of saying a *version* of something that branched from you lives forever.

So A) is my version of the self incompatible with quantum immortality and being able to say *I* woke up on Mars, and B) is this the minority opinion of the self within philosophy? How else can I explain serious philosophers and physicists not listing their assumptions when they talk about transporters and quantum immortality. Where can I go that discusses this within the example of teleporters and quantum immortality?

Comment: The thought experiments can always be done, but in reality, they *can't*. For a discussion about the self, they are useful though. That's why the only way for you to reappear on Mars, is to decompose you, transfer the particles to Mars, and compose them again there. In which case you could just as well could have gone there by the interplanetary subway. Beaming up information about your particles and make a new body with this information (with different particles) will not create another you since you stay behind on Earth.

Comment: @Methadont I still think you need to say why a decomposed you into particles can't be copied into another set of particles to say the first part then. Once decomposed we are implying they are just particles, and you are temporarily gone. Particles are all the same. If recombination is essentially "put this atom here and this atom here", I can just go get another set of atoms and do it twice. I think you *maybe* can make this first version (not beaming) work with some additional assumptions like only the particles that came from you can be used (why I don't know) and definitions, but not as is.

Comment: To reconstruct the particles from which I'm made (after, say my death) in a new me, you need the information of the *whole* universe. You have to do the same if you send my particles to Mars. The particles that you send is me being dead. You just can't wake me up while I'm dead. This involves knowing the whole history of my particles and all particles that have lead to the particles from which I'm made. This means knowing the history of the whole universe (or at least the particles in the past lightcone). Impossible.

Comment: The computer doing the calculation needs to know the *whole* history *all* particles in your past lightcone. But the computer is part of this past too. So it can't do the calculation, as the information about the particles that do the calculation isn't involved.

Comment: @Methadont I pretty much agree wholeheartedly, but I will say we don't seem to talk about particles in this way usually - describing a single electron in terms of the entire rest of the universe. And that no two electrons are really the same ever. I think we may ultimately have to do something like that for all of physics at some point, but most theories and conversations simplify from that picture.

Comment: The point is that even for like particles (on Mars) you have to know how to place them as in my body. You can say that the particles in my body have a certain place in phase space, of course. But *how* to give another set of particles the same position in this phase space? The only way is to let them evolve in the way the real particles have evolved. So this can't be done by means of a program. The particles just have to be put in place by the process of evolution. You can't program evolution. The computer must be the whole universe surrounding the evolving particles, so to speak.

Comment: @Methadont But if I travel to New York by bus or by boat, I am still me when I get there regardless of how I traveled. My entire past history and the history of the universe doesn't seem necessary to define the self in this sense. I shouldn't need to let the entire universe evolve *exactly* as  it did to get me again. Otherwise don't I have to say if I choose to go somewhere by bus or by boat I will be a different me/self depending on which I choose? Then I must be different at every single moment of every day. A new me every moment in time, and we only think we are the same through time.

Comment: Yes indeed. And luckily so. But your mom is still needed. You can be yourself if your mum spoke another language, or if she was born on another planet too. But in all these cases the history of the whole universe in your past lightcone is involved. If your mom wore a green dress, you must still know the history of the whole universe (in your past lightcone) to recreate you. You can introduce variations, but that makes it even more complicated. For all possible you's a history is involved.

Comment: @Methadont I think you present a perfectly consistent and well defined notion of the self in accord with the laws of physics. Better than any I've heard. I don't know if it is exactly how I would define self, but I see your logic. Thanks for the discussions

Comment: It's my pleasure! :) I don't see the self as particles *only*. There is soul involved obviously. But I think this is inherent to particles. We can know this inside soul only by feeling or consciousness or whatever. Without this soul, there is no conscience. Something like that...

Comment: So I don't think we can live on in a Matrix program on a computer.

Comment: Isn't teleportation similar to sleeping? In a way, your conscience gets turned off in the evening and turned on again - same as with teleportation. If you believe the self is purely a product of the brain's particles and processes, then it's hard to argue why the obivous difference (when sleeping you continue to exist physically) should be decisive for saying that your conscience continues to exist when sleeping but not when teleporting.

Comment: @JannPoppinga I agree there is a bit of overlap. However, in any meaningful notion of teleportation other than just shooting your whole body, there is some kind of decomposition process of your body. Maybe the your body's particle are rearranged to fit into a smaller container or what-have-you. It's the necessary decomposition and then recomposition that maybe make teleportation distinct from sleep. Maybe in sleep my *awareness* muted, but everything of me is still there in a large sense. In teleportation, the container of my particles is not me in any sense.

Comment: @JannPoppinga And to decompose and recompose a body, you need instructions. Where to put your brain and your arms. If you have a set of particles that will become you once put into their proper arrangements, I see no physical impediment to applying the same rules to another equal set particles and getting two me's. I had to record how I was decomposed into a known specific arrangement of particles, and know how I will recompose them. Particles are just particles. Rules on paper are just rules on paper. If I can teleport like this, I should be able to make two me's. Sleep isn't quite this imo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contemporary philosopher Derek Parfit discussed such a Earth-to-Mars teleportation in his book *Reasons and Persons* according to reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasons_and_Persons#teletransportation_problem):

> At time 1, there is a person. At a later time 2, there is a person. These people seem to be the same person. Indeed, these people share memories and personality traits. But there are no further facts in the world that make them the same person. Parfit's argument for this position relies on our intuitions regarding thought experiments such as teleportation, the fission and fusion of persons, gradual replacement of the matter in one's brain, gradual alteration of one's psychology, and so on. For example, Parfit asks the reader to imagine entering a "teletransporter," a machine that puts you to sleep, then destroys you, breaking you down into atoms, copying the information and relaying it to Mars at the speed of light. On Mars, another machine re-creates you (from local stores of carbon, hydrogen, and so on), each atom in exactly the same relative position. Parfit poses the question of whether or not the teletransporter is a method of travel—is the person on Mars the same person as the person who entered the teletransporter on Earth? Certainly, when waking up on Mars, you would feel like being you, you would remember entering the teletransporter in order to travel to Mars, you would even feel the cut on your upper lip from shaving this morning. Then the teleporter is upgraded. The teletransporter on Earth is modified to not destroy the person who enters it, but instead it can simply make infinite replicas, all of whom would claim to remember entering the teletransporter on Earth in the first place. Using thought experiments such as these, Parfit argues that any criteria we attempt to use to determine sameness of person will be lacking, because there is no further fact. What matters, to Parfit, is simply "Relation R," psychological connectedness, including memory, personality, and so on.

Thus according to Parfit, we could know all the facts about a person's continued existence and not be able to say whether the person has survived after the perfect teleportation in principle. He concluded that we're mistaken in assuming that personal identity is what matters in survival; what matters is rather psychological connectedness (memory and character) and psychological continuity. Identity is not as determinate as we often suppose it is, but instead such determinacy arises mainly from the way we talk. People exist in the same way that nations or clubs exist. Following David Hume, Parfit argued that no unique entity, such as a self, unifies a person's experiences and dispositions over time. Therefore personal identity is not "what matters" in survival. A key Parfitian question is: given the choice between surviving without psychological continuity and dying but preserving psychological continuity through someone else's future existence, which would you choose? Parfit argues the latter is preferable.

So in this sense, there're 2 types of self, one is the appearance induced ego-like self which may not exist at all, another is soul-like self which correspond to one's memory, characters and psychological continuity...

Comment: Now I finally know to whom I talk at night... :)

Comment: Thank you for the very relevant post and quote. Could you explain "A key Parfitian question is: given the choice between surviving without psychological continuity and dying but preserving psychological continuity through someone else's future existence, which would you choose? Parfit argues the latter is preferable." What do you mean through someone else's future existence? Like allow yourself to die fully, and be content your good actions will be embodied by other people you connected with in life - instead trying and failing to be immortal, because we can't be?

Comment: @JKusin thx for your comment! Indeed you're certainly right your referred scenario is a clear example and one correct interpretation of Parfit's views, and he used this teleportation thought experiment to challenge the traditional self-interest rational theory with moral consequentialism in his book as referenced here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derek_Parfit). Also this seems in line with most world religions' inheritance lineage in the spirit of immortality of their respective worldviews.

Comment: @DoubleKnot thanks so much for the resources and info. I was feeling a bit trapped that none of the philosophers I knew of touched on these issues.

Comment: This story still states that it is possible to teleport the particles (and their history) you are made up from to Mars. This si simply not possible. You can't make a copy of you or me in (in time or in space) this universe because of the simple fact that there would be two of you then! If a copy of me is made then all particles have to be the same (including their history). This can never be achieved. Maybe in a future universe, you can appear for a second time.

Comment: @Methadont thx for your comment! Parfit is a philosopher not quantum physicist or MWI specialist. He just assumes science and technology is perfect enough to realize his ideal teleportation *thought experiment* which is used to further his own moral theory in challenging traditional consequentialism ethic views.

Comment: Hi there! When doing the thought experiment, it depends on how you teleport. If you literally teleport (by shooting up the particles you are made of to Mars) it will still be you. If you teleport bt sending information and make up a body of the same *kind* of particles on Mars, it will *not* be you. Is this reasonable?

Comment: Problem with these thought experiments is that it can also be used for regular happenings. Who's to say that the me that is now, don't die when I go to sleep? Nobody experiences continuous conciousness, at the very least, most people need to sleep.

Comment: @Methadont Parfit holds a thorough reductive/eliminative physicalism POV so for him in philosophical principle there's nothing preventing teleporting the *same* person by "destroying" and "reassembling" its physical constituents. He believes once technology is advanced enough this *could* happen at least in theory, if not in practice due to all kinds of errors. Forget about all the mental part, from a thorough materialist's view your ego-like identity is an illusion, so for your question he exactly answered both cases could be achieved to be same you (in terms of physics).

Comment: But what if it *fundamentally* can't be achieved in practice? Is it of use speculating about it?

Comment: @Methadont so his point is actually right now we don't even need this imagined teleportation experiment to be realized, just like any thought experiment, from this exercise we can *argue for* a Buddhism's Anatta-like no-self identity of person. Today's you is not the same as yesterday's you, and the seeming continued question from your line yesterday is the psychological character and continuity which is the true identity of you which I called the soul-like self. It has huge moral/ethical utility and consequence though ultimately it may be an illusion based on physicalism/materialism.

Comment: But if the soul-like me can be copied by means of a thought experiment, does this imply that a soul-like-me cannot be identified? Is the soul-like identity such that I am everybody? aren't soul-like experiences coupled to the ego-like identity. I may be different from yesterday's me but I can remember it. If I can't I still feel the soul and if I'm dead this soul is not there anymore. For other people, the soul is still there though. Even if they can't remember.  If the soul is dead so am I (the ego-like me).

Comment: @Methadont soul-like self cannot be identified by usual visual or auditory senses, by can be identified via our cognitive capacities. For example, I can easily identify today's you is almost same as yesterday from your style of writings and strong character to be always curious to follow up questions, even I never see your appearance or hear your voice... Parfit's point is this identity identified via such cognitive criterion is preferable and truer than the usual appearance-based ego-like self which is a fake identify but mistaken as the primary by most people naturally...

Comment: Sorry for reacting a bit late! I was involved in the game of life. It's really addictive! Like real life... So even if I have never seen you I can know that it's you. But then again, how do I know if it's really you? I mean, I know it's really you in this case, but isn't a super strong supercomputer able to reply in the way you do? I'm not comparing you to a computer! But imagine it *could* reply in that way (I think this is easier to imagine than meeting a real flesh-like copy of you). When identity is real? Only the fact that you once sent a copy of a philosopher makes it real, but imagine.

Answer (score 4):

I think you *can* imagine wakening up on Mars after your body has been decomposed into its constituents (elementary particles) which are transported to Mars and subsequently composed back into the form had on Earth. You could just as well have traveled to Mars without the decomposing and composing but let's assume. If you are decomposed on Earth your consciousness obviously fades to zero (assuming it to be tied to matter). If the matter is composed again on Mars your consciousness will gradually wake up. Just as after an operation by a physician. You will wake up.
On the other hand, if the information about the composed elementary particles is sent to Mars (*if* this information can be acquired without disturbing the composition), and this information is used to compose your body out of a reservoir with elementary particles, you will not think that it is you who wakes up. The elementary particles you are composed of have to stay the same particles. A clone of you is made up of different particles, so the clone is not you.
The particles in your body when you were born are almost all replaced by new ones. By other particles. Are you a different person from who you were in childhood? No, of course not. The particles can be changed over time. If you replace each particle of your body with the same kind of particle the result will still be you. In the case of constructing another body on Mars, based on the information of your body on Earth, there are no particles of your body in earlier times involved. This is why the body on Mars doesn't wake as another you. If you built a person, say you, out of the same kinds of particles (with the right relation wrt each other) the result won't be you. It's another person.
The result can only be you if *the same* particles out of which your body (including your brain) consists are used for creating another you. This is obviously not possible if the creation means that there will be two of you. The created new "you" is a different person. A person identical in make-up to you, living in a parallel world will always be different from you, even if they live in different times, as the particles in both universes are always different from each other. In *our* universe it *could* be you in the future. If someone in the future would find all elementary particles you were made up when you were ten years old and if could manage to reconstruct you, it *could* be possible that you experience to be a new ten-year-old walking the streets.
If a new collection of elementary particles would emerge after a new big bang (assuming a sequence of big bangs) it depends on how you see the particles in the in-between-bangs universes. If you consider them as being the same particles you can be reborn again (if the particles evolve again as they did in a universe that gave birth to you). If you consider them as a whole new collection of particles (as in the [Ekpyrotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekpyrotic_universe) universe, it's questionable but reasonable. According to the logic I used it would be impossible for you to reappear. Because different particles appear they will never give rise to the same you. But I'm not sure if this logic can be applied to two temporally disconnected *universes* instead of temporally disconnected regions in *one* universe. That is, if a whole new *process* of new particles (the process of evolution) gives birth to your body, as did a process taking place in an earlier universe (with different particles) it could be another you. You can't create another person in this way on Earth. For that, you would have to recreate the entire process of evolution. In fact, you would have to recreate the entire universe... Needless to say that that's impossible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126449/discussion-on-answer-by-methadont-distinction-between-two-types-of-self).

Answer (score 1):

What we consider "the same person" is purely conventional. That's Parfit's point about there being nothing in the world that makes either answer to the question true or false. We often say things like this in everyday life: "He wasn't the same person after his traumatic brain injury." Another acquaintance of the person might protest that the same person they've always known is still there underneath all of the observable effects of the neurological damage. Who's right? Continuity of personal identity over time is a matter of degree. And the identity of the particles we're composed of is, in my view, a much less relevant factor than continuity of personality and memory. Others have different intuitions on that, but I can't see what considerations can possibly arbitrate between the conflicting intuitions, since sameness of self is purely conventional and a matter of degree.

In the duplicator version, both you and your duplicated self would share the same past self, while also presently being two different persons. One person became two people. What's incoherent about that? Your duplicated self would certainly consider your past self their past self too, because that's everything they remember and how they became who they are and came to believe, desire, and value all that they believe, desire, and value. Would they be wrong to consider that their past self?

Comment: But if everyone were watching me from afar walk up to a duplicator ray, get scanned, then go sit down while the new copy of me is shuttled to Mars, there would be no disagreement like you have above. Original me is on Earth and Copy me is on Mars and no one watching would disagree. I, Original me, would never have a doubt in my identity. Spectators neither. And Copy me would wake up and realize he is the copied one.

Comment: Yeah, I agree everyone would consider you Original You and copy you Copy You, as should the Copy You themselves. But I think Copy You also has a legitimate claim to consider your past self to be also their past self. Why can't two distinct present selves have one and the same past self?

Comment: My present sense of self is a product of my knowledge of my past and current awareness. My continually evolving-with-the-present sense of self has been growing and changing since I began to record memories. And it factors in things like knowing cells from each parent were grown in my mother, which lead to a fetus being birthed. Copy me's self knows its matter and cells came from disparate places, coming together mere moments ago using lasers and biochemical machines. These selves don't overlap. Until someone shows something with a sense of self can undergo mitosis I am not convinced by this.

Comment: That seems to beg the question. If we had one of these duplicators, wouldn't that be sufficiently functionally similar to mitosis? I also don't see why material continuity is a necessary condition of continuity of personal identity. If scientists discovered that neurons replace themselves every several years just like most other cells of the body do, would you then no longer consider your self of ten years ago to be your past self?

Comment: I'm not sure how to resolve this current line of inquiry tbh. But as for my original question, how does same past-self, distinct current selves resolve teletransportation (in this case sans duplicator version) or quantum immortality? When authors say *you* wake up on Mars or *you* always survive a game of Russian roulette, a person is still dying aren't they? It seems to reassure this present me very little even if there can be two persons with the same identity.

Comment: Apologies for digressing down rabbit-holes. I don't take the teletransportation sans duplicator scenario to result in same past self with distinct present selves. Only the duplicator case has that result. Sans duplicator, I'd see it as just same self, no different than traveling to Mars by other means of transportation. But I do get your concern. Maybe there's a temporal-perspective split in our intuitions. The "me" on this side of the transformation event feels like that wouldn't be me on the other side, but the "me" on the other side would feel that they were the same person as present me.

Comment: The rabbit-hole was fine it showed me some things I do not know how to resolve. Thanks for the answers